# Removing axis argument from numpy argmin, but still vectorized

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

So i have the following lines of code

```py
np.argmin(distances, axis = 0)
```

Here distances is a distances matrix between k centroids, and n points. so it's a k x n matrix. 
So with this line of code i'm trying to find the closest centroid for each point, by taking the argmin along axis 0.

My goal is to have a similar vectorized code without the axis argument, as it is not implemented in the fork of numpy i'm using.

Any help would be nice :)

Comment: Does the fork have `np.sort(..axis)`?

Comment: @Divakar I am afraid it does not. It would seem that axis is always a problem

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized one -

```
def partial_argsort(a):
    idar = np.zeros(a.max()+1,dtype=int)
    idar[a] = np.arange(len(a))
    return idar[np.sort(a)]

def argmin_0(a):
    # Define a scaling array to scale each col such that each col is 
    # offsetted against its previous one  
    s = (a.max()+1)*np.arange(a.shape[1])

    # Scale each col, flatten with col-major order. Find global partial-argsort. 
    # With the offsetting, those argsort indices would be limited to per-col
    # Subtract each group of ncols elements based on the offsetting.
    m,n = a.shape
    a1D = (a+s).T.ravel()
    return partial_argsort(a1D)[::m]-m*np.arange(n)
```

Sample run for verification -

```
In [442]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(11,9999,(1000,1000))
     ...: idx0 = argmin_0(a)
     ...: idx1 = a.argmin(0)
     ...: r = np.arange(len(idx0))
     ...: print (a[idx0,r] == a[idx1,r]).all()
True
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, you are always so helpful :) There seems to be only one issue with this. I cannot use the argsort() function, as that has not been implemented yet.. I know.. Annoying.

Comment: @Shadesfear What kind of primitive NumPy branch are you on? :)

Comment: i'm on Bohrium https://bohrium.readthedocs.io/ . So automated gpu acceleration of numpy code.

Comment: @Shadesfear Does it support array-assignment and np.flatnonzero?

Comment: @Shadesfear array-assignment?

Comment: Yes, It does support that. @Divakar

Comment: @Shadesfear Check out edits please. Also from the docs on the package, it seems argmin along an axis is supported - https://bohrium.readthedocs.io/users/python/api.html?highlight=argmin#bohrium._bh.ndarray.argmin, right?

Comment: Yes i agree that argmin along an axis should work. But I get an error whenever i try to use it.